# 16Amp plug to 6Amp plug

Tags: high-current, plug, socket

I have 6Amp socket all around my home, but my washing machine has 16Amp plug.
Can convertor be used to plug 16 Amp  in 6 amp socket somehow?
 I am in India, so electricity is 240v50Hz

Answer (score 4):

> Can I power a 16 A load on a 6 A socket?

No.

Your sockets are rated to carry 6 A safely. If you connect a 16 A load they will overheat and risk fire.

> Can I run the washing machine on a 6 A socket?

Yes **if** the washing machine draws **less than 6 A**. at 240 V this would be a maximum power of 240 x 6 = **1440 W**. You will find this information on the rating plate.

Answer (score 3):

The whole sense of having plugs with lower rating is that you shouldn't attach larger loads to that plug or circuit.

So, no.

Comment: so there so device like transformer convert low to high voltage kinda stuff

Comment: What's unclear about "no"?

Comment: It's not a matter of _voltage_ @murmansk. It's more about how much current will be drawn.

Comment: @KingDuken device has rated current as 0.6 amp, so i am thinking 16Amp to 6 amp plug convertor might work

Comment: I'm almost certain it doesn't draw 0.6 A. That would only be 144 W, not enough to make hot water in acceptable time.

Comment: So. "No" means "no".